# Explanation ArrayList

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

How to create a list of values ​​ordered pairs, for example list1 [(x, y), (x1, y1) ...].??

After learning how to create this list, I need to know how to get the x value to the User in the list enter and search a next value of x and show the ordered pair (x, y)?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to create a list of `Point`. First of all define the Point class,

```
public class Point
{
  private int x,y;
  public int getX() { return x;}
  public int getY() { return y;}
  public void setX(int x) { this.x=x;}
  public void setY(int y) { this.y=y;}

  public Point() {}
  public Point(int x,int y) { this.x=x; this.y=y;}
}
```

and create `List<Point>.`

```
List<Point> points=new ArrayList<Point>();
```

Add point object references,

```
points.add(new Point(3,3));
points.add(new Point(4,5));
```

return a point object reference,

```
System.out.println(points.get(0).getX());
```

Comment: the User will enter a value of x, then I need to check on my list ready has a value equal to the entered User

Comment: @GDawson - Please edit your post. You should have to put more description and code you have tried into your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class (say `Point`) that stores two variables, `x` and `y`. You can then create a `List` as follows:

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
```

To insert data in the list,

```
points.add(new Point(2,3));
```

Comment: What do you want to map? If you want to map `x` to `y`, then you wont be able to have two objects that have the same `x` value.

Comment: I got it. we cannot have duplicates with Map. Thanks

Comment: the User will enter a value of x, then I need to check on my list ready has a value equal to the entered User

Comment: You can either search linearly or store the index of a point in a map which has `x` coordinate as the key.

Answer (score 0):

you have several options

1. use multi-dimensional arrays like [][]
2. use a ArrayList with generics, use a Object of an array with size 2 or a class with two variables X and Y as your generic, like `List<YourObject> = new Arraylist()<YourObject>;`